# How to tell if a page has been reloaded in Firebug or Chrome Developer tools?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-devtools, firebug

I have a page where if I select an entry from a drop down menu, part of the page flickers and the url changes. I didn't write the code for this page but I think it did something in the background to load or reload at least part of itself.

But when I look in the Network tab of Chrome developer tools or Firebug, I don't see a network call to the new url. So how could the url of the page change without a network call being shown in these tools?

Is there a way to tell with either of these tools if window.onload or document.ready has fired at this point?

Comment: *"So how could the url of the page change without a network call being shown in these tools?"* [History API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/History_API)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use breakpoints on event listeners to see if certain events are triggered or not. See the [documentation](https://developer.chrome.com/devtools/docs/javascript-debugging#breakpoints-on-javascript-event-listeners).

[image: Breakpoints on event listeners]

Or, Chrome devtools can list the event handlers registered on any element. Just inspect the element and expand the Event Listeners panel.

[image: Event Listeners panel]